# Listing all files available in Spark cluster stored on Hadoop HDFS using Scala or Python?

Tags: python, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

What is the most efficient way to list all the files names that are locally available in Spark? I'm using Scala API, however, Python should also be fine.

Comment: Listing the files on HDFS is not Spark-specific. Just use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus()`.

Comment: this doesn't really work but thanks to your hint I know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack


 val fs = FileSystem.get( sc.hadoopConfiguration )
 var dirs = Stack[String]()
 val files = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]
 val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
 dirs.push("/user/username/")

 while(!dirs.isEmpty){
     val status = fs.listStatus(new Path(dirs.pop()))
     status.foreach(x=> if(x.isDirectory) dirs.push(x.getPath.toString) else 
     files+= x.getPath.toString)
 }

files.foreach(println)
```