# Filter spark paths on `input_file_name`

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there an effcient way to filter in the input files to a spark dataframe based on `input_file_name` without reading the content of all the files?

I have a path on S3 with many large gzipped csvs (`xx.csv.gz`) that I'm reading in via `spark.read.csv("path/to/csvs/*")`. I would like to filter the input based on the file name without resorting to glob pattern.

However, when I add the input file name to the Dataframe using `withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())` and filter it using a `where` I see that all files get processed and read.

Is there a more efficient way to do this without resorting to processing all of each file?

Thanks!

Comment: you can always query the filesystem directly, bypassing Spark. If it's HDFS you can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478377/listing-all-files-available-in-spark-cluster-stored-on-hadoop-hdfs-using-scala-o

Answer (score -1):

glob patterns are doing the filtering for you. It's not the most efficient bit of code against object stores, but it's doing the match.

Is there some S3 performance/throttling problem you are hitting?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly glob patterns are not powerful enough for the filtering I would like to do (say some string extraction and calculation). which is why I had asked 'without glob patterns'. Using `input_file_name` ends up reading the entire file even if its data gets filtered out. Ideally spark would push that filter down and just read the file name, skipping the reading of the file contents. I'm curious if there's an efficient spark way to do that short of prefiltering using the filesystem directly ala @jamborta's comment above.

Comment: Not sure. I know that for streaming you can define your own input source (which can do whatever filtering you want), maybe you can do something for batch queries.